# Loop over posts in _index.html

Tags: hugo, go-templates

I'm using [Hugo](https://gohugo.io/) to build my own website

I'm having a problem I have a _index.html page, and that is my homepage

But when I try to loop over posts, it just prints text no posts are shown

```
 {{ range .Pages.ByDate }}
                    <div class="w-full md:w-1/2 md:px-3 mt-6">
                        <article class="h-full flex flex-col rounded-lg shadow-lg>
                            <h1>Post</h1>
                        </article>

                    {{ end }}
```

Comment: Can you post what's your repository layout? `{{ .Pages  }}` only looks for `.md` files in `posts/` subdirectory. Also you can try to debug template using `{{ printf "%#v" .Pages }}`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Where is `_index.html` located? If it's under `content/`, then raw Go-Template code will not work there. If it's under `layouts/`, then it is a Go Template but it is not the correct name for the layout of your home page. Possible names for the home-page layout file include:

```
layouts/index.html
layouts/home.html
layouts/_default/index.html
layouts/_default/home.html
(and more)
```

For details, see:

- https://gohugo.io/templates/homepage/
- https://gohugo.io/templates/lookup-order/#examples-layout-lookup-for-home-page

After you figure out what directory and what file name you want to use, you probably want to use something other than this inside the `range`:

```
<h1>Post</h1>
```

For example, maybe this:

```
<h2>{{ .Title }}</h2>
```

Comment: thank you, that was the problem I had my index.html in the wrong directory

Answer (score 3):

You could do the following:

```
{{ range  ( where .Site.RegularPages "Type" "posts" ) }}
    <h4>{{ .Title }}</h4>
{{ end }
```

Where `posts` is the name of the directory containing the posts (i.e., `your_blog/content/posts` in my case where I renamed `posts` directory to `blog` the above will look like this:

```
{{ range  ( where .Site.RegularPages "Type" "blog" ) }}
    <h4>{{ .Title }}</h4>
{{ end }
```